# Explicitly-specified template parameter packs

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

Let's say, I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t... Is> struct E {};

template <typename... Ts, size_t... Is>
void func (E<Is...>, Ts...) {std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;}

int main()
{
    func(E<1,2,3>{}, 1, 'a');
}
```

It works perfectly fine and produces

```
void func(E<Is ...>, Ts ...) [with Ts = {int, char}; long unsigned int ...Is = {1, 2, 3}]
```

However, if I replace `func` call with `func<int, char, 1, 2, 3>(E<1,2,3>{}, 1, 'a');`, it will cause the compilation error, i.e.,

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed
```

Why compiler forbids the explicit specification of multiple parameter packs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from the rules for template argument deduction.

When you explicitly specify the template parameters for `func`, the compiler will match it to the first parameter pack *greedily*. The compiler does not figure out that once you start putting `int`s in the parameters, it should start substituting for `Is...`.

Instead, it will continue substituting for `Ts...`, and you'll get an error message along the lines of:

```
expected a type, but got 1
```

for the 3rd explicitly specified parameter.

You can see this if you specify *only* the `Ts...`, like this:

```
func<int, char>(E<1,2,3>{}, 1, 'a');
```

which compiles just fine.