# Compile time nested loop using `std::integer_sequence`

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

In the code below, I have worked out a compile time nested loop that calls a `print` function that prints the number to screen. The 1D and 2D version work, but the 3D version triggers a `note: candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction` error. What do I do wrong?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


// 1D processing.
template<int I>
constexpr void print()
{
    std::cout << I << std::endl;
}


template<int... Is>
constexpr void test(
        std::integer_sequence<int, Is...> is)
{
    (print<Is>(), ...);
}
// End 1D.


// 2D processing.
template<int I, int J>
constexpr void print()
{
    std::cout << I << ", " << J << std::endl;
}


template<int I, int... Js>
constexpr void print(
        std::integer_sequence<int, Js...> js)
{
    (print<I, Js>(), ...);
}


template<int... Is, int... Js>
constexpr void test(
        std::integer_sequence<int, Is...> is,
        std::integer_sequence<int, Js...> js)
{
    (print<Is, Js...>(js), ...);
}
// End 2D.


// 3D processing.
template<int I, int J, int K>
constexpr void print()
{
    std::cout << I << ", " << J << ", " << K << std::endl;
}

template<int I, int J, int... Ks>
constexpr void print(
        std::integer_sequence<int, Ks...> ks)
{
    (print<I, J, Ks>(), ...);
}


template<int I, int... Js, int... Ks>
constexpr void print(
        std::integer_sequence<int, Js...> js,
        std::integer_sequence<int, Ks...> ks)
{
    (print<I, Js, Ks...>(ks), ...);
}


template<int... Is, int... Js, int... Ks>
constexpr void test(
        std::integer_sequence<int, Is...> is,
        std::integer_sequence<int, Js...> js,
        std::integer_sequence<int, Ks...> ks)
{
    // THIS CALL FAILS DURING COMPILATION.
    (print<Is, Js..., Ks...>(js, ks), ...);
}
// End 3D.


int main()
{
    constexpr std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 4, 8> is{};
    constexpr std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 4> js{};
    constexpr std::integer_sequence<int, 32, 64> ks{};

    test(is); // 1D example.
    test(is, js); // 2D example.
    test(is, js, ks); // 3D example, FAILS.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm unfortunately not sure why exactly this fixes it, but in the 3D `test()` function, omit the second and third template parameters to the call to `print()`: `(print<Is>(js, ks), ...);`

Comment: @G.Sliepen. Indeed, this fixes it. It would be great to learn why.

Comment: My guess is that in `print<Is, Js..., Ks...>()`, the boundary between `Js...` and `Ks...` gets lost, but if you let it autodeduce based on the arguments, it does know where the boundary is.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for it failing is that the overload of your function `print` which takes three template arguments has **two variadic template parameter packs** `template<int I, int... Js, int... Ks>`. Multiple template parameter packs are only valid if the compiler can deduct them from the function arguments (see [temp.param/14](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param)):

> A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]) of the function template or has a default argument ([temp.deduct]).
> A template parameter of a deduction guide template ([temp.deduct.guide]) that does not have a default argument shall be deducible from the parameter-type-list of the deduction guide template.

When **explicitly specifying the template parameters the compiler will therefore match them greedily to the first parameter pack**.
This is even the case when [combining type and non-type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305390/explicitly-specified-template-parameter-packs). Only then **deduction occurs from non-template function arguments**.

This means [in your case](https://wandbox.org/permlink/D8nRYmuBJPdOld7m)

```
(print<Is, Js..., Ks...>(js, ks), ...);
```

will actually ignore the wished candidate template

```
prog.cc:64:16: note: candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction
```

as something like

```
print<I, Js..., Ks...>()
```

would actually match something like

```
template <int I, int... Ts>
constexpr void print()
```

`Js...` and `Ks...` will be combined to `Ts... = {Js..., Ks...}` leaving none of the specified template parameters to the following packs as - by the standard - it must be possible to deduce them from the non-template function arguments.

---

In order to see why allowing a syntax like in your initial code could be problematic just imagine a template function with two parameter packs `Ts` and `Ss`, where `Ss` can be deducted from the function arguments but `Ts` can't be deducted and instead has to specified explicitly,

```
template <typename... Ts, typename... Ss>
void func(Ss... ss) {
  return;
}
```

which is called with

```
func<int,double>(int{1}, double{7.0});
```

This would be ambiguous (`Ts = {int, double}, Ss = {int, double}` or `Ts = {}, Ss = {int, double}`) and therefore lead to problems with the logic in your initial code but is unambiguous (`Ts = {int, double}, Ss = {int, double}`) if you match the the parameters greedily and only then deduct from the function arguments.

---

In your case simply **removing the right-most parameter pack**

```
(print<Is, Js...>(js, ks), ...);
```

or **both of them**

```
(print<Is>(js, ks), ...);
```

makes the compilation succeed as `Js` and `Ks` can both be deducted from the function arguments `js` and `ks`. [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H22ouqc4sXLYrOp1)

Comment: Alright, so imagine I would like to write out the three template arguments for clarity, how should I do this?

Comment: @Chiel I don't think there are ways of doing so. If you want to be more precise about which function will be called you could rename the different `print` functions to have unique names.

Comment: It is clear to me which function is called. I would only like to know what is happening under the hood if I omit the template argument, because my actual use case is a bit more complex. Your answer solves my problem, but I do not really understand it fully.

Comment: @Chiel I see, I modified my answer. Maybe it is more clear now.

Comment: @Chiel Off-topic: Had a look at your microhh code. Really awesome stuff! I am a big fan of DNS/LES simulations, fluid flow instabilities and atmospheric flows. What are you using for visualistion? Only Python and in combination with matplotlib?