# Misunderstanding about non-deducible function template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer, template-meta-programming

From *C++ Templates - The Complete Guide 2nd edition*:

> Moreover, such parameters can't usefully be placed after a template parameter pack or appear in a partial specialization, because there would be no way to explicitly specify or deduce them.
>
> ```
> template<typename ...Ts, int N>
> void f(double (&)[N+1], Ts ... ps); // useless declaration because N
>                                     // cannot be specified or deduced
> ```

where *such parameters* refers (I think) to the template parameters corresponding to those template arguments that can never be deduced. I.e. in the example above `N` is the parameter that cannot be deduced because `N+1` is "too complicated to be deduced".

But why specifying it is not possible? I understand that it's not possible to specify `N` and let `...Ts` be deduced, but why isn't it possible to specify them all? In other words, what is wrong in specifying `Ts=[int]` and `N=2` via the following?

```cpp
    double x[3];
    f<int,2>(x,1);
```

Comment: `...` is too greedy, it consumes `2`, too. By the time when a compiler realizes that `2` is not a type, it's too late. Doing it other way is theoretically possible but would probably complicate parsers that are already pretty complicated.

Comment: Oh, ok... Since the kinds of template parameters (non-type, type, and template) are well separated, I didn't think that _by the time_ could be an argument. As in, why should the compiler consume 2 while it's looking for types?

Comment: In the general case they are not that well separated. For example, you could have `A` being a type, `using A = int;`, or a non-type `constexpr int A = 2;`. What would a compiler do with `f<int, A>` then? My guess is that parsers don't even try to make an analysis here.

Comment: I know this is a purely theoretical question, but it's worth mentioning that in practice, this is rarely an issue since you can just put the parameter packs at the end of the list of template arguments.

Comment: @Enlico I am not sure if your post is motivated by a very similar post that was posted yesterday but I tried to give an answer to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68186697/9938686). The last paragraph outlines briefly why your last example could be problematic in the more general case.

Comment: @2b-t, no, it isn't. I'm simply reading the book I linked. +1 to your answer there.

Comment: @Enlico I see. Maybe the post even though not fully related clarifies it a bit. In your example it would work if the compiler would distinguish between type and non-type templates but in other cases it might be problematic. Therefore the standard is pretty strict about it: All parameters after a template parameter pack, no matter if type of non-type have to be either defaulted or be deductible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I.e. in the example above `N` is the parameter that cannot be deduced because `N+1` is "too complicated to be deduced".

Formally, this is [[temp.deduct.type]/5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.type#5.3)

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - [...]
> - /5.3 A non-type template argument or an array bound **in which a subexpression references a template parameter**.

As is already covered in the following Q&A:

- [Which part of the C++ standard prevents explicitly specifying this template's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68157960/which-part-of-the-c-standard-prevents-explicitly-specifying-this-templates-ar)

particularly that in a template-head of a function template

> ```
> template<typename ...Ts, int N>
> // ... function template
> ```

as per [[temp.param]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.param#14.sentence-3)

> A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed by another template parameter **unless that template parameter can be deduced from the *parameter-type-list*** ([dcl.fct]) of the function template **or has a default argument** ([temp.deduct]).

specifically as per the special rule for function templates (due to function template argument deduction), the template argument `N` *must be deducible from the function's parameter list*. As per [[temp.deduct.type]/5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.type#5.3), it is not, and `f` in the following example can never invoked (overload resolution will never consider it a viable candidate):

> ```
> template<typename ...Ts, int N>
> void f(double (&)[N+1], Ts ... ps);
> ```

whereas the following functions can both be found by overload resolution:

```
template<typename ...Ts, int N>
void g(double (&)[N], Ts ... ps);   // N deducible from function parameter

template<typename ...Ts, int N = 2> // N has a default-template-argument
void h(double (&)[N+1], Ts ... ps);
```

---

> But why specifying it is not possible?

As discussed in the linked to Q&A, although it "would make sense for a compiler to support this", the standard does not, and a leading template parameter pack greedily includes all explicitly provided template arguments, even those that would not be valid as part of the expanded pack (e.g. non-type template arguments to a type template parameter pack).